# How to shift specific memory values with other values previously stored in another register

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying to access the value of the second byte at register R3 and then replace that value with the value stored in R8.

I came up with this `LDRSB LSR[R3,#1], R8` where I used SB because that second byte is also a signed number, but apparently this isn't accepted in assembly code syntax, what would be the equivalent of what I tried to do?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/v55zx7rxj shows that `ldrsb` is the right instruction to load a byte.  IDK what you're trying to shift.  If it's the load result, then you need a separate instruction.  If you're trying to shift the value in memory, you need two more instructions (to store the shift result).  ARM is a load/store machine: only specific load and store instructions can access memory, and any math they do is on the address, not the value loaded.  Unlike x86, you can't do a memory-destination shift.  Also, if it's signed, are you sure you want a logical right shift instead of arithmetic?

Comment: But whatever you're trying to do, if you can express it in C, GCC and/or Clang can show you at least one way to do it.

Comment: ARM is a load/store architecture.  It the values are in registers, you don't use 'ldr'.  You can use `bfi`, `mov`, `and`, etc. that directly manipulate registers.   For example, https://godbolt.org/z/z9zdGKza6

Answer (score 0):

If the value is in memory, use a single-indexed addressing mode to access the second byte:

```
strb r8, [r3, #1]   @ store R8 to second byte of memory at R3
```

If the value is in a register, use a `bfi` instruction:

```
bfi r3, r8, #8, #8  @ copy low 8 bits of R8 into bits 8--15 of R3
```